# Formatting of the infile shows as /dev/nvme0n1 instead of /dev/sda

Tags: command-line, ddrescue

In terms of using Ddrescue to clone the drive, I noticed that my infile is to be /dev/nvme01n instead of /dev/sda. The likelihood of it this based on the SSD drive.

As long as I know which is my source, does it matter ?
I have noticed that it differs in names like **sdd or sde, sdb, nvme01n**

As to writing the command ddrescue-f /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/sda...logfile..

Comment: `/dev/nvme01n` would be an NVMe solid state device. `/dev/sda` would be a SCSI (or SATA) device, which could be either an SSD or HDD. As for "does it matter", specifying an input and output for something like ddrescue *is* important.

Comment: @matigo  I meant to say that does it matter if I know the source is nvme01n and my output is sda

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Suppose I am cloning my ssd drive to sata drive ssd, I should format it this way /dev/nvme01 dev/sda

Comment: Yes that is correct